# Getting HTTP status 400 error while submitting a form in spring mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-400

I have two webpages.One is "user.jsp" and "person.jsp".when i click on "Register" button it goes to "user.jsp" and when i click on submit button its showing "Http Status 400".

PersonController.java

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    //For add and update person both
        @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p,@ModelAttribute("user") User u){
            String name = p.getName();
            System.out.println("name is :"+name);

            if(name == null || name == "") {
                System.out.println("user is"+name);
                return "user";
            }

            else{
                //new person, add it
                this.personService.addPerson(p);
            }

            return "redirect:/persons";

        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {


                // new user, add to DB
                this.userService.addUser(user);

            return "redirect:/persons";

        }
```

PersonDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(p);
        logger.info("Person updated successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for(Person p : personsList){
            logger.info("Person List::"+p);
        }
        return personsList;
    }

@Override
    public Person getPersonByName(String name)  {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Person> usersList = session.createQuery(
                "from Person ").list();
        if (usersList.size() == 0)
            return null;
        Person usrObj1 = usersList.get(0);
        return usrObj1;
    }
```

UserDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(user);
        logger.info("User saved successfully, User Details=" + user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(user);
        logger.info("User updated successfully, User Details=" + user);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<User> usersList = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        for (User user : usersList) {
            logger.info("User List::" + user);
        }
        return usersList;
    }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public User getUserByName(String fullName)  {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<User> usersList = session.createQuery(
                "from User ").list();
        if (usersList.size() == 0)
            return null;
        User usrObj1 = usersList.get(0);
        return usrObj1;
    }
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String country;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "id="+id+", name="+name+", country="+country;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "fullname")
    private String fullName;



    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private Integer phone;

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "FullName")
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }



    @XmlElement(name = "Password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "EmailId")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "PhoneNo")
    public Integer getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Integer phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
```

PersonServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        this.personDAO.addPerson(p);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updatePerson(Person p) {
        this.personDAO.updatePerson(p);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        return this.personDAO.listPersons();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        return this.personDAO.getPersonById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Person getPersonByName(String name) {
        return this.personDAO.getPersonByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removePerson(int id) {
        this.personDAO.removePerson(id);
    }
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
 @Service
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

        private UserDAO userDAO;

        public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
            this.userDAO = userDAO;
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void addUser(User user) {
            this.userDAO.addUser(user);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void updateUser(User user) {
            this.userDAO.updateUser(user);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public List<User> listUsers() {
            return this.userDAO.listUsers();
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public User getUserById(int id) {
            return this.userDAO.getUserById(id);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void removeUser(int id) {
            this.userDAO.removeUser(id);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public User getUserByName(String fullName) {
            return this.userDAO.getUserByName(fullName);
        }

    }
```

person.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/person/add" ></c:url>

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
<table>
    <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="id">
                <spring:message text="ID"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
            <form:hidden path="id" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    </c:if>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="name">
                <spring:message text="Name"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="name" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="country">
                <spring:message text="Country"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="country" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">


                <input type="submit"
                    value="<spring:message text="Add Person"/>" />


            <input type="submit"
                    value="<spring:message text="Register"/>" />

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    
</form:form>
```

user.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/user/add"></c:url>

            <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="user">
                <table width="400px" height="150px">
                    <c:if test="${!empty user.email}">
                        <tr>
                            <td><form:label path="id">
                                    <spring:message text="ID" />
                                </form:label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"
                                    disabled="true" /> <form:hidden path="id" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${!empty user.email}">



                </c:if>
                    <tr>
                        <td><form:label path="fullName">
                                <spring:message text="Full Name" />
                            </form:label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="fullName" /></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td><form:label path="password">
                                <spring:message text="Password" />
                            </form:label></td>
                        <td><form:input type="password" path="password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><form:label path="email">
                                <spring:message text="Email" />
                            </form:label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><form:label path="phone">
                                <spring:message text="Phone" />
                            </form:label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="phone" /></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><c:if test="${!empty user.email}">
                                <input type="submit"
                                    value="<spring:message text="Update Details"/>" />
                            </c:if> <c:if test="${empty user.email}">
                                <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Submit"/>" />
                            </c:if></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
```

Any suggestion or advice in this it will be helpful for me
THanking You

Comment: add  method="POST" your forms and try it please.

Comment: remove <form:hidden path="id" /> in person.jsp and try please

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt i tried that but still showing the same

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

> 400 Bad Request
>   The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, too large size, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the http method attribute of your form:

```
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="user">
```

Then, the default method is `GET`, therefore it wont never found a controller because your controller `/user/add` expects `RequestMethod.POST`

If you add the method attribute It will work:

```
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="user" method="POST">
```

Comment: Then! open browser developer tool and check what is the url invoked